# Zurb Foundation dropdown button not showing drop-triangle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I am new to Zurb's Foundation and have come across an unusual quirk.  I have placed a dropdown button on a form, and am using it as a 'state-picker'.  However, no matter which dropdown button style, size or color I choose, the dropdown 'triangle' image doesn't show.  SimilarlyThe call to the button is inside a Rails 3 *select* method and the options are off in a helper file.  Here is the code:

```
  <div class="large-2 columns">
    <%= f.select :billing_state, options_for_select(us_states), {}, 
      :class => "small radius button dropdown" %>
  </div>
```

See the photo here:

[image: Missing dropdown triangle]

I have verified that a regular html dropdown button request is working on the same page with:

```
<a href="#" class="small radius button dropdown">foo</a>
```

See here:

[image]

I am stumped!  I have even tried the 'Split Button', which doesn't have a 'Split pipe & triangle'.  Any ideas?  cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zurb uses a completely different way of styling things to the rails select html output.  Passing a class to the select method doesn't really help.  I've found that I needed to code the html manually in my projects when using Zurb and the dropdowns.

I haven't found the interaction between form helpers and Zurb as straightforward as with Twitter Bootstrap.

This page explains the Zurb approach to styling select boxes using custom form. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/custom-forms.html

Basically they use styled span's.

Hope this helps.